# Is this partial function template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-specialization, initializer-list

I came up with this after answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369464/template-function-gives-no-matching-function-for-call-error)

I had a simple function template (C++11):

```
template<class elem_t, class list_t>
bool in_list(const elem_t& elem, const list_t& list) {
   for (const auto& i : list) {
      if (elem == i) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

But GCC emitted warnings because it doesn't seem to like deducing a template parameter as a std::initializer_list.  So, without thinking, I made a specialization:

```
template<class elem_t>
bool in_list(const elem_t& elem, std::initializer_list<elem_t> list) {
   for (const auto& i : list) {
      if (elem == i) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

This worked.  No more warnings.  But when I looked again and thought about it, I remembered that C++ does not support partial template specialization on function templates.  But that is what this appears to be.  My only guess is that this is allowed because std::initializer_list is still dependent upon the template parameter, so it is, in essence, a different template.  But I'm not sure if this is how it is supposed to be (isn't there a gotw about templates not overloading?).

Is it standard behavior to accept this?  And why?

And as a bonus question, why does GCC not like deducing a template parameter as a std::initializer_list? It seems quite silly to expect me to copy and paste the code and just replace the parameter with a std::initializer_list.

The warning message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:33:43: warning: deducing ‘const list_t’ as ‘const std::initializer_list<int>’ [enabled by default]
test.cpp:6:6: warning:   in call to ‘bool in_list(const elem_t&, const list_t&) [with elem_t = int, list_t = std::initializer_list<int>]’ [enabled by default]
test.cpp:33:43: warning:   (you can disable this with -fno-deduce-init-list) [enabled by default]
```

When called by `in_list(3, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});`

EDIT:  Apparently deducing a template parameter as an initializer_list is an extension according to the working draft for my version of GCC ([cite](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html)).  So new question: Is this still an extension as of the final c++11 standard?  If so, this would mean that it would be necessary for me to add the second function for standards-compliant code.  Thanks for all your help!

EDIT2:  The compiler dialect flag appears to be removed for GCC 4.7, so it seems like the issue was resolved, but I don't know *how* it was resolved.

Comment: No, it's not template specialisation, and you can tell just by looking at the syntax. What is it? Overloading I think, but I'll let someone more knowledgeable answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure which.  I'm not sure.  Since it forms a subset but is still a template, I would say it is (at least semantically) a specialization.  But syntactically it looks more like overloading.  But I'm not sure exactly how it overloads or what the standard says.

Comment: I'm looking through the standard now and collecting some info that might help.

Comment: Ack, it's too long and complicated.

Comment: @Robert, I suggest taking the initializer_list as an rvalue-reference, to avoid copies.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Good idea.  Anyone know why GCC doesn't like deducing a template argument as std::initializer_list<T>?  Why does it issue a warning for this?

Comment: wait, I thought you said the warning was for taking the initializer_list by const reference, not for deducing a template argument.

Comment: I did.  I was wrong.  Sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: What exactly does GCC say when it doesn't like deducing that template argument?

Comment: I posted the warning.  It works fine, so I can safely ignore it, but I never like just ignoring warnings as they often hint at a deeper problem.  If GCC feels the need to warn me about doing something it's probably because I don't know what I'm doing :D

Comment: Yes, apparently you do need the second overload for standards-compliant code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4763493/726361

Comment: for your initializer list deduction question, also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/7699963/34509

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using what @Ben Voigt said in the comments on the other answer, I have gathered some relevant standard quotes:

> §14.5.6.2
>
> A function template can be overloaded with other function templates
> and with normal (non-template) functions. A normal function is not
> related to a function template (i.e., it is **never considered to be a
> specialization**), **even if it has the same name and type as a
> potentially generated function template specialization**.

So that rules out function template specialisation as what you're doing, because even if two function template overloads could potentially generate the same function, it's not specialisation. So it's overloading.

> Such specializations are distinct functions and do not violate the one definition rule (3.2).

So they're distinct functions and that's why it's not erroring.

> §14.5.6.2.1
>
> If a function template is overloaded, the use of a function template
> specialization* might be ambiguous because template argument deduction
> (14.8.2) may associate the function template specialization with more
> than one function template declaration.

This is priming is for what we both already saw, which is that `in_list(a, b)` where `b` is an `initializer_list` appears to match both function templates.

(*Note that "function template specialization" here doesn't mean specialising a function template, it means a function template that has been instantiated with a type. So with `template<typename T> f();`, `f<int>()` is a function template specialisation.)

So we use what is called *partial ordering of overloaded function templates* to resolve this:

> Partial ordering of overloaded function template declarations is
> used in the following contexts to select the function template to which a function
> template specialization
> refers:
>
> — during overload resolution for a call to a function template specialization (13.3.3);
>
> — when the address of a function template specialization is taken;
>
> — when a placement operator delete that is a function template specialization is selected to match a placement operator new (3.7.4.2, 5.3.4);
>
> — when a friend function declaration (14.5.4), an explicit instantiation (14.7.2) or an explicit specialization (14.7.3) refers to a function template specialization.

Ok, so that's when partial ordering is for. This is what it does:

> Partial ordering selects which of two function templates is more
> specialized than the other by transforming each template in turn (see
> next paragraph) and performing template argument deduction using the
> function type. The deduction process determines whether one of the
> templates is more specialized than the other. If so, the more
> specialized template is the one chosen by the partial ordering
> process.

And then you get into the long and laborious process of determining which template is more specialised, which you can read about if you want, but it's really complicated and I probably don't understand it all (and plus, I don't have enough time to write about it :)).

Comment: So if I changed the declaration of the second snippet to template<class elem_t>
bool in_list<elem_t, std::initializer_list<elem_t>>(const elem_t& elem, std::initializer_list<elem_t> list) then it would be illegal?  And that since it is legal, the C++ standard has the compiler follow arcane rules that determine that the second is more specific.  So, in essence, it works by magic? :D

Comment: (referencing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101516/why-function-template-cannot-be-partially-specialized)

Comment: @RobertMason yes, that would be illegal, because _partial_ template specialisation is illegal. And yes, the C++ standard has the compiler follow long rules about which one is more specialised and therefore which one to "select" to be used. So yeah, magic :)

Answer (score 3):

That's not partial specilization. What you are doing is overloading function.

Comment: `in_list(a, b)` when `b` is an initialiser list seems to match both templates. What are the rules for looking up overloads on templates like this?

Comment: @Seth: The more specific overload, using `initializer_list`, will be preferred.  The rules are UGLY, and I doubt there are more than ten people in the world (I'm not one) who actually understand them *completely*.

Comment: @Seth: sections 13.3, 14.5.6.1, 14.5.6.2, 14.8.2.4, 14.8.3  I'm pretty sure there's an existing question for which one of the answers includes a translation into almost-understandable.